# Asus SW5-012 trying to do dual boot Linux

Tags: linux, windows, boot

I have an *Asus Aspire SW5-012* and cannot disable secure boot.

I get into BIOS just fine. It's 5.0 setup utility. The system BIOS version is V1.13. When I go to the security tab, secure boot mode is on standard and refuses to respond. It's a touchscreen and secure boot setting refuses to respond.

I have a live XUbuntu 18.4. I believe that the version is USB READY and plugged in. Windows Explorer sees it, but it refuses to boot. I know the touch screen won't work after that and I don't care.

Comment: try to create an Supervisor Password, That will be in the bios, probably under security tab.

Comment: My bad, before you do that, try to enable CSM.

Comment: There is no option for csm...i read if you don't do it before win 10 installation you can't do it. Doesn't make sense but I checked every tab. Under the boot tab I have secure boot set to disabled and usb as the top of boot order. But under security secure boot says standard and doesn't react to touches or mouse clicks.  And I have had a supervisor password set and is very annoying. Thank you

Comment: What did you mean by refuses to boot? Details plz.

Comment: Did you follow the ubuntu guide to setting up a Bootable usb drive? You will need to do that if you didn't. https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0,

Comment: Yes pancake, I have a bootable live usb. It boots into Windows 10 just fine and I can see all the files on it through Windows explorer. I think because it's more a tablet than a laptop this may just not be possible

Comment: So does the bios not see it?

Comment: Bios doesn't see thumb drives. I think my problem is I have 5.0 setup utility and it's unlike any bios I've ever seen, and I've seen alot. It's a touch screen with a detachable keyboard. I'm beginning to hate it. I just want linux even if no touch screen cause it's portable.

Comment: You said it was Asus but when I search that, I get acer, what is it?

Comment: I read that you get more options in newer bios versions for the Acer Aspire SW5-012, like switching between UEFI and Lagacy boot.

Comment: I found this, this might be the answer. https://superuser.com/questions/878637/how-to-boot-acer-aspire-switch-10-from-external-media

Comment: Damn I'm stupid. It's definitely an acer. I have an Asus but no problems with it. Sorry. My fault

Comment: Well f me. I know for a fact I have a bootable usb, tested it on a desktop after following your directions. Same as it was before though as far as Windows explorer sees. So I read your link and f12 got me to boot option menu but only Windows boot manager shows up.

Comment: My bad I didn't tell you what answer I meant, it was John Stiles answer.

Answer (score 0):

[How to boot Acer Aspire Switch 10 from external media?](https://superuser.com/questions/878637/how-to-boot-acer-aspire-switch-10-from-external-media) Here. John Stiles said that  only the micro usb port works in the Bios so you will need an adapter. Also here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8muPGQY8x3g (You can see in this video that he has his usb drive plugged into an male micro usb to usb type A female adapter)

Comment: Your amazing. I ha e hours looking things up all to no avail. I know exactly the cable I need but I don't have one. I guess I need an Amazon visit. I'll let you know after I get it. Thank you again.

Comment: While I have no idea what language that YouTube video was that appears to be the answer. Nice find. I'll let you know

Comment: Hey....just got back from the worst vacation ever, helping a friend move from Texas to Cali. I got the usb female to micro male adapter. The switch 10 sees it in Windows explorer and I booted from XUbuntu from yet another desktop merely by changing boot order and pressing f12 on startup. Even though I've followed all John stiles directions only Windows boot manager shows up with f12. Thinking it's not possible